# Show databases of MySql server

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, database

Does anybody know, how to show databases in C#? I know thats possible by executing a sql command `show databases`, but i dont know how to configure reader. Anybody please help me.

**EDIT**: I found a solution:

```
    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(this.constr);
        MySqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = "show databases";
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                string row = "";
                for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
                    row += reader.GetValue(i).ToString();
                listBox1.Items.Add(row);
            }


        }
        catch (MySqlException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Number.ToString());
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

    }
```

Comment: do u want to see the schema of database ?????

Answer (score 2):

```
string myConnectionString = "SERVER=localhost;UID='root';" + "PASSWORD='root';";
MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(myConnectionString);
MySqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
command.CommandText = "SHOW DATABASES;";
MySqlDataReader Reader;
connection.Open();
Reader = command.ExecuteReader();
while (Reader.Read())
{
  string row = "";
  for (int i = 0; i < Reader.FieldCount; i++)
       row += Reader.GetValue(i).ToString() + ", ";
       comboBox1.Items.Add(row);
}
connection.Close();
```

Comment: Can't see any difference between my and your solution, except the absence of of try-catch block and combobox use.

Answer (score 1):

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);

SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand ("show databases",conn);
conn.Open();
SqlDataReader reader = com.ExecuteReader();
DataTable dt = new DataTable;
dt.Load(reader);
DataRows[] rows = dt.Rows;
```

Think you can then view the data rows

That said, if you already have the connection string, there's no reason not to open MSqlServer or whatever and view it from there...

Comment: Look, this is my error:
http://prntscr.com/3iqhz
And I don't have a `DataRows[]` in a System.Data namespace.

Comment: Oh right uh. I think there's a "Get Rows" or something like that.

Comment: No http://prntscr.com/3iqjh and no http://prntscr.com/3iqjm .
Oh wait, i will try foreach.
Foreach no: http://prntscr.com/3iqk9 .-