# How to get the list of database servers/ database instances in mysql using C#?

Tags: c#, mysql, database

I need to list the database servers in the mysql installed on my machine using C#.Net. Is it possible , please suggest.

Comment: You could try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7784701/show-databases-of-mysql-server Also possible duplicate?

Answer (score 0):

> list the database servers

Do you mean list of all existing databases? If yes, then you can probably use `SHOW DATABASES` command to list out all database currently present.

Already answered

[Show databases of MySql server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7784701/show-databases-of-mysql-server)

Answer (score 0):

Use this query to get database list

```
SELECT table_schema AS Databases FROM information_schema.tables
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this method to get the running service. The Path gives the service MySQL..

```
ManagementClass mc = new ManagementClass("Win32_Service"); 
 var Instances = mc.GetInstances().Cast<ManagementObject>().ToList(); 
 foreach (ManagementObject o in Instances) 
 { 
 if (o.GetPropertyValue("PathName").Contains("mysqld.exe")) 
 /// is a mysql service 
 }
```